# How to set http timeouts for Amazon AWS SDK for PHP

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I'm using the Amazon AWS SDK for PHP (namely, version 2.7.16) to upload files to an S3 bucket. How can I set a timeout for http/tcp operations (connection, upload, etc.)? Although I've googled a lot I wasn't able to find out how.

Sample code I'm using:

```
$awsS3Client = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
        'key' => '...',
        'secret' => '...'
    ));

$awsS3Client->putObject(array(
            'Bucket' => '...',
            'Key'    => 'destin/ation.file',
            'ACL'    => 'private',
            'Body'   => 'content'
        ));
```

so I'd like to set a timeout on the `putObject()` call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eventually I helped myself:

```
$awsS3Client = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
        'key' => '...',
        'secret' => '...'
        'curl.options' => array(
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
        )
    ));
```

Looks like AWS PHP uses curl internally, so network related options are set this way.

Comment: Aws\AwsClient::factory is now deprecated : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.AwsClient.html#_factory
Using the constructor directly seems to do the same job.

Answer (score 3):

With [SDK version 3 this can be configured using the `http` configuration key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_configuration.html#config-http).

```
$awsS3Client = Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'key' => '...',
        'secret' => '...',
        'http' => [
            'connect_timeout' => 5,
            'timeout' => 10,
        ]
    ]);
```